# Oracle SQl splitting the week date

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm new in the world of sql and i'm not that good with dates.
I need help with a query.
I can't figure out how to split the date from a week into days.

Having the table like this.

| ID | Stardate | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24/09/2023 | 745 |
| 2 | 24/09/2023 | 353 |
| 3 | 01/10/2023 | 442 |

What i want is to split the week in days, for example like this.

| ID | Stardate | date_days | Days | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24/09/2023 | 24/09/2023 | Sunday | 745 |
| 1 | 24/09/2023 | 25/09/2023 | Monday | 745 |
| 1 | 24/09/2023 | 26/09/2023 | Tuesday | 745 |
| 1 | 24/09/2023 | 27/09/2023 | Wednesday | 745 |
| 1 | 24/09/2023 | 28/09/2023 | Thursday | 745 |
| 1 | 24/09/2023 | 29/09/2023 | Friday | 745 |
| 1 | 24/09/2023 | 30/09/2023 | Saturday | 745 |
| 2 | 24/09/2023 | 24/09/2023 | Sunday | 353 |
| 2 | 24/09/2023 | 25/09/2023 | Monday | 353 |
| 2 | 24/09/2023 | 26/09/2023 | Tuesday | 353 |
| 2 | 24/09/2023 | 27/09/2023 | Wednesday | 353 |
| 2 | 24/09/2023 | 28/09/2023 | Thursday | 353 |
| 2 | 24/09/2023 | 29/09/2023 | Friday | 353 |
| 2 | 24/09/2023 | 30/09/2023 | Saturday | 353 |
| 3 | 01/10/2023 | 01/10/2023 | Sunday | 442 |
| 3 | 01/10/2023 | 02/10/2023 | Monday | 442 |
| 3 | 01/10/2023 | 03/10/2023 | Tuesday | 442 |
| 3 | 01/10/2023 | 04/10/2023 | Wednesday | 442 |
| 3 | 01/10/2023 | 05/10/2023 | Thursday | 442 |
| 3 | 01/10/2023 | 06/10/2023 | Friday | 442 |
| 3 | 01/10/2023 | 07/10/2023 | Saturday | 442 |

Comment: So you want to take 7 days from the start date and include the name of the day? Why is id=2 excluded? Because it has the same date as id=1?

Comment: Yes, i excluded id = 2 because i was lazy to write it in the example since it has the same starting date.

Comment: Might be good to think about what's better: One person being to lazy to write a clear question or many people who are confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *row generator* problem. Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from your_table_name;

        ID STARTDATE         QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 24/09/2023        745
         3 01/10/2023        442
```

Query; note that you shouldn't avoid duplicates with the `distinct` keyword. It works OK on small data sets, but as number of rows in `your_table_name` grows, query works worse and worse. The one that follows should behave way better.

```
SQL> select id,
  2         startdate,
  3         startdate + column_value - 1 as date_days,
  4         to_char(startdate + column_value - 1, 'Day', 'nls_date_language = english') days,
  5         qty
  6  from your_table_name cross join
  7    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                        connect by level <= 7
  9                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 10  order by id, date_days
 11  /

        ID STARTDATE  DATE_DAYS  DAYS                   QTY
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ----------
         1 24/09/2023 24/09/2023 Sunday                 745
         1 24/09/2023 25/09/2023 Monday                 745
         1 24/09/2023 26/09/2023 Tuesday                745
         1 24/09/2023 27/09/2023 Wednesday              745
         1 24/09/2023 28/09/2023 Thursday               745
         1 24/09/2023 29/09/2023 Friday                 745
         1 24/09/2023 30/09/2023 Saturday               745
         3 01/10/2023 01/10/2023 Sunday                 442
         3 01/10/2023 02/10/2023 Monday                 442
         3 01/10/2023 03/10/2023 Tuesday                442
         3 01/10/2023 04/10/2023 Wednesday              442
         3 01/10/2023 05/10/2023 Thursday               442
         3 01/10/2023 06/10/2023 Friday                 442
         3 01/10/2023 07/10/2023 Saturday               442

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to solve this, and came up with this.

```
WITH date_series AS (
SELECT
    ID,
    StartDate,
    StartDate + LEVEL - 1 AS date_days
FROM
    your_table_name
CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= 7
)
SELECT distinct
t.ID,
t.StartDate,
ds.date_days,
TO_CHAR(ds.date_days, 'Day') AS Days,
t.QTY
FROM
your_table_name t
JOIN
date_series ds
ON
t.ID = ds.ID
order by id, startdate, date_days;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c28bc/9

Comment: Is there a reason this isn't done in one statement like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c28bc/14 ?

Comment: The answer looks good but my query is running for ever or is making duplicates..

Comment: @EdmCoff no reason, didn't think in that way.

Comment: @Marius have you tried the one shared by edmcoff? Using distinct should remove duplicates.

Comment: Yes, i managed to remove the duplicates but the query is running forever.. The only time i managed to see the results is when i put the startdate between 1-2 weeks difference range and a specific id but that's not whati'm looking for.

Comment: @Marius no. of rows in your table?

Comment: @marius Please check if this improves performance. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c28bc/19

Comment: @jakbar Same result, running forever. And my table has millions of data and hundred are the same but with different week date.

Comment: @Marius have your tried the answer shared by littlefoot? Does it improve performance??

Comment: @jakbar Yes, that query works for me.. is taking some time to show results since i have millions of data but is working. Thank you for your time and help.